# French playground term: monkey bars

Tags: terminologie, jeux, enfants

I can't find good translations for [monkey bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jungle_gym) (also called jungle gym or climbing frame, a structure in a playground where children may climb). Do they have those in France, and if so what do you call them?

[image: Monkey bars]

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/swing#Translations, http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/slide#Translations_2, http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/playground#Translations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

La photo représente une cage à écureuil pour aire de jeu.

L'écureuil petit, fragile, agile, élégant (« Regarde comme il est adorable avec sa queue en panache ! ») donne une image affectueuse de la petite enfance.

Le singe, quoique malin (être malin comme un singe), peut énerver à cause de ses mimiques (« Arrête tes grimaces, arrête de faire le singe »), et correspond à un enfant un peu plus âgé.

Toutefois on comprendrait parfaitement quelqu'un qui dirait à son enfant « va jouer dans la cage aux singes », même si je n'ai entendu cette expression qu'au début de l'installation de ce type de jeu dans les parcs citadins.

La cage à écureuil est aussi une cage (pour contenir un écureuil) qui contient une roue à écureuil.

Un autre type de [cage à écureuil](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cage_%C3%A0_%C3%A9cureuil) est synonyme de roue à écureuil.

Comment: J'aime beaucoup votre raisonnement (c'est très expressive), mais avez-vous un réference qui montre cet usage?  Tous que je trouvait suggèrent qu'on utilise «cage à écureuil» seulment pour les anciennes méchanismes ou pour le petit roue pour les rongeurs (voir I. A. 2.a) de le [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cage)

Comment: Après une recherche rapide je n'ai n'ai trouvé que cet exemple http://www.eveiletjeux.com/produit-121098/cage-a-ecureuil.htm -  En tout cas, cette appellation  était courante à PARIS (à la toute fin du dernier millénaire).

Comment: @Micromégas: après enquête auprès de professeurs des écoles on appelle bien ça cage à écureuil dans les écoles, et ce genre d'installation est très fréquent dans les écoles françaises.

Comment: @Laure  Super.  Il est bon d'avoir cette information. J'ai demandé à quelques amis et ils ne savaient pas!

Answer (score 3):

Playground: *terrain (ou aire) de jeu*, *bac a sable* if with sand, swing: *balançoire*. I don't know the other ones. Oh, and slide is [toboggan (or glissoire, only in Canada though)](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toboggan_%28glissoire%29)

Comment: The real question is monkey bars (the others are easily found in any dictionary).

Comment: https://blackmaki.fr

Answer (score 3):

[Les barres de suspension](http://www.hc-sc.gc.ca/cps-spc/sport/equip-play-jeu/index-fra.php)

J'ai aussi trouvé le terme «cadre à grimper», accompagné de plusieurs [exemples](http://www.lappset.fr/Produits/Recherche_de_produits/Liste_de_recherche_des_produits.iw3?categories=S0014) légèrement différents de votre photo.

Comment: Et s.v.p. ignorez l'hystérie au sujet du risque dans ce lien!

Comment: Dans cet ordre d'idées, j'ai aussi trouvé "structure tubulaire" http://www.univers-loisirs.com/accueil/structure-tubulaire ce n'est pas très poétique comme nom.

Comment: Les* barres de suspension* pour moi c'est autre chose qu'on voit assez souvent dans les aires de jeu. *Cadre à grimper* me semble approprié, même si je ne devinerais pas forcément de quoi il s'agit sur le coup.

Comment: @Stéphane:  Oui, j'ai entendu simplément «les barres à grimper» quand j'étais dans l'aire de jeu avec ma fille. Quand j'ai fait plus du recherche sur la terme «barres de suspension» il me semblait que s'agit du sport gymnastique.  Mais je suis incapable de trouve autre réference demi-officielle.

Comment: Les barres de suspension me semblent être ce que j'ai grandi en appelant un "pont de singe": une série de barre parallèles auxquelles on se suspend en avançant, un peu comme une échelle mise à l'horizontale. Je crois que les Européens appelle cela un *portique*.

Answer (score 2):

A défaut d'un terme précis en français, ou disons à défaut d'un terme couramment utilisé et reconnu (j'avoue n'avoir jamais entendu *cage à écureuil* en Lorraine), j'aurais tendance à me reporter au [terme général](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agr%C3%A8s_de_loisirs) le plus proche. **Agrès** est moins spécifique mais correspondra probablement assez bien dans de nombreux contextes.

(Mais mon lointain passé de gymnaste m'induit peut-être en erreur ?)

Comment: Il manque la notion de jeu et de plaisir gratuit dans le mot agrès, terme vieilli pour désigner le gréement de bateaux ou les appareils pour pratiquer la gymnastique,.

Comment: @cl-r Mais la question ne demandait pas spécifiquement de faire passer dans l'appellation tout ce "paquet sémantique". Il était question de savoir comment désigner ces structures. La [page wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cage_%C3%A0_%C3%A9cureuil) que tu cites ne contient aucune référence au cas qui nous intéresse ici. Et, par exemple, dans le contexte d'une municipalité décrivant ses installations pour enfants, j'imagine plus facilement le choix d'un terme neutre comme *agrès*. Remarque intéressante, quoi qu'il en soit !

Comment: Une mairie parlera plutôt d'aire de jeu [intégrée] pour enfants, la notion d'agrès renvoie d'abord à une discipline olympique, et éventuellement aux salles de sport qu'elle a à gérer. J'ai trouvé cage à écureuil dans la définition : http://www.idealo.fr/prix/3262696/wickey-captain-s-tower.html

Comment: En tout cas, je suis d'accord sur un point : *cage à écureuil*, c'est nettement plus rigolo ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Quand j'étais en primaire, on appelait ça "**cage à poule**".

Answer (score 0):

La traduction que nous utilisons dans l'industrie des aires de jeux pour les élément de type "Monkey Bars" est: échelle horizontale.